# How to increase a numeric attribute value in a database by a percentage using SQL

Tags: sql, database

I have 2 tables in a database as follows;

```
Instructor (id, name, department_id, salary)
Department (department_id, dep_name, location)
```

I want to increase the salary of a set of Instructors in a particular department, say I want to increase the salary of all instructors from Physics Department (say department id=1) by 10%. How can I do that using an sql query?

Comment: People of StackOverflow won't do your homework.

Comment: @Luc M you are wrong... as demonstrated by dasblinkenlight

Comment: @luksch I was surprised when I saw his reputation...

Comment: @Luc M, This is my first post.. I am really new.No help for us I understood.Thanks!!!

Comment: @Deepal Jayasekara don't take it the wrong way. Luc M tried to point out that you are supposed to put some effort in your questions. One approach to this is to state what you have tried so far.

Comment: @DeepalJayasekara you should show you have tried anything before asking. This is, at least in my opinion, the only thing that is wrong! :)

Comment: THanks Lucia, @luksch. I thought I have to first retrieve the value and then multiply. I will do as you say if I ask any. Thanks a lot for both of you again. I really appreciate your words. :)

Comment: Thanks all!! I am really couraged now.. Thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Increasing by ten percent means multiplying by `1.1`, so all you need to do is a simple update:

```
UPDATE Instructor
SET salary = salary * 1.1
WHERE department_id=1
```

Long explanation: recall that 10% means `salary * 10 / 100`, or `salary/10`. Expanding `salary + salary/10` gives `salary * (1 + 1/10)`, or `salary * 1.1` in decimal notation.

Comment: Thanks.. Really thanks since you gave me an answer for my first question in stack overflow.

Comment: @DeepalJayasekara You are welcome, and welcome to the site! If the answer works for you and you are no longer looking for an improved answer, consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark next to it. This would give you your first badge on Stack Overflow.

Comment: ok @dasblinkenlight, Now I did it. Thanks a lot again. :)